# Chrome 6.0.477.0: Blockquote error causes text duplication

Tags: bug, status-declined, beta

This error is browser limited, and I know that beta browsers are not supported, however is there any fix or solution for the error that occurs to me when I try and blockquote text?

For example, if I blockquote the text: **site design / logo © 2010 stack overflow internet services, inc; user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required**

The following will result:

with attribution required
with attribution required> site design / logo © 2010 stack

> overflow internet services, inc; user
>   contributions licensed under cc-wiki
>   with attribution requiredwith attribution required
>   with attribution required

Comment: You can just type a ">" before the paragraph you want to blockquote and that will be enough up until the next line break. I've stopped using the quote button.

Comment: @rchern - me too, apart from on longer paragraphs.

Comment: For a continuous paragraph, you only need a single ">" at the start.  You don't need one on each wrapped line.  If there is a hard line break, you can just add another ">".

Comment: Duplicate on MSO:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56610/bug-using-quote-button-in-google-chrome-on-windows

Answer (score -1):

Indeed there is a solution; use the current non-beta released version of the browser, Chrome 5. :)

Comment: I would if I could figure out how to downgrade the darn thing without having to uninstall first and lose all my settings! :P

Comment: Uhm @Jeff can I assume this bug will not transfer into the stable version once Chrome 6 becomes non-beta?